# Nginx on-the-fly config reload leads to errors

Tags: nginx, configuration

I tried to run a "nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" but I got:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
[Exit 1]
```

Then I run a

```
 fuser -k 80/tcp ; service nginx restart.
```

I tried again with "nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" but still the same error "[emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)"

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you reload nginx.
What you are trying is starting nginx *again*, `-c` just specifies the configuration file it should use.
Use `service nginx reload` or `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` to reload it.

Comment: Ops I thought it was the command to reload the config "silently"

Comment: I'd look into signals for config reload, they're rather typical.

Comment: SIGHUP is the silent reload signal for NGINX (on the master process). but using 'reload' attribute to the init.d script is easier for most.

Comment: Does reload imply worker process to change id?

Comment: Depends on the actual init script, but usually it is also just sending SIGHUP. For more information on what happens, see here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html